# Unity c# cписок не успевает инициализироваться в конструкторе

Tags: c#, unity3d, список, конструктор, инициализация

Делаю 2d тавер-дефенс, решил сделать конструктор для удобного создания башен, но столкнулся с ошибкой `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` при назначении башне спрайта и характеристик(во втором классе, строчке `selftower = gl.AllTowers [(int)selftype];` чуть ниже.

Проблема заключается в `gl`или `FindObjectOfType<GameLogic>();` поскольку именно они возвращают `null`, но вот почему они не работают, для меня не очевидно. Я так же пробовал `GetComponent<GameLogic>().AllTowers [(int)selftype]` но и это не помогло.
Практически на 100% уверен, что моя проблема в какой-то мелкой ошибке, которой я не замечаю, посмотрите пожалуйста свежим взглядом...

Есть два класса:

Конструктор:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tower{
    public float range,Cooldown;
    public Sprite Spr;
    public Tower(float range, float cd,string path){
        this.range = range;
        Cooldown = cd;
        Spr = Resources.Load<Sprite> (path);
    }
}
public class Towerprojectile{

}
public enum TypeTower{
    First_tower,Second_tower
}
public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Tower> AllTowers =  new List<Tower>();
    public void Awake(){
        AllTowers.Add (new Tower (40, 0.3f,"TowerSpr/First"));
        AllTowers.Add (new Tower (70, 0.9f,"TowerSpr/Second"));
    }
}
```

Класс логики башен:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Towersrc : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Projectile;
    GameLogic gl;
    Tower selftower;
    public TypeTower selftype;
    private void Start(){
        gl = FindObjectOfType<GameLogic>();
        selftower = gl.AllTowers [(int)selftype];
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = selftower.Spr;
    }
```

Как реализовывал Initialize(2-й способ, который я пробовал):

```
public void Initialize(){
        AllTowers.Add (new Tower (40, 0.3f, "TowerSpr/First"));
        AllTowers.Add (new Tower (70, 0.9f, "TowerSpr/Second"));
    }
```

В Tower:

```
gl = FindObjectOfType<GameLogic>();
//      GetComponent<GameLogic> ().Initialiaze ();
        gl.Initialize();
//      selftower = GetComponent<GameLogic>().AllTowers [(int)selftype];
        selftower = gl.AllTowers[(int)selftype];
```

Спасибо за внимание, при необходимости, могу дать ссылку на гитхаб проекта.

Comment: Дело не в пустом списке `AllTowers`, а в нулевой ссылке `gl`.

Comment: @Igor хм, а в чем ошибка с `gl`?я допускал, что проблема с gl и обращался через `GetComponent<GameLogic>().AllTowers [(int)selftype]` но это тоже не помогло.Или тут тот же ошибка?

Comment: `GameLogic` - объект этого типа где-нибудь создается?

Comment: @Igor `GameLogic gl;` во втором классе, GameLogic это название класса, в котором у меня конструктор.

Comment: `GameLogic gl;` - это декларация переменной. Где-нибудь есть создание инстанса класса `new GameLogic()`?

Comment: @Igor но ведь `GameLogic` это `MonoBehaviour`, и то что вы предлагаете невозможно и обращение к ним должно идти через `GetComponent()`?Или я что-то не так уловил?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko а разместить этот объект визуально вы не забыли?

Comment: @PavelMayorov поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko `FindObjectOfType` не создает объект, а ищет то что вы разместили в визуальном редакторе. Точную терминологию я не знаю, но где-то на сцене у вас должен валяться GameLogic чтобы вы могли найти его через `FindObjectOfType`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо огромное,  это то, что было нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш компонент `GameLogic` должен быть добавлен в сцену и присутствовать в ней  перед созданием башен. Он у вас инициируется на `Awake` и по идее должен срабатывать раньше чем будет вызван в `Start` у башни. Ваш конструктор на сколько я понимаю должен быть единственным в сцене, можно посмотреть в сторону синглтона и создать в классе статик ссылку на конструктор(то бишь на самого себя), чтобы получать доступ к конструктору в любом классе без использования `Find`.

```
public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour {
public List<Tower> AllTowers =  new List<Tower>();
public static GameLogic instance = null;

public void Awake(){
    if (instance) 
    {
        Destroy(this);
        return;
    }
    instance = this;
    AllTowers.Add (new Tower (40, 0.3f,"TowerSpr/First"));
    AllTowers.Add (new Tower (70, 0.9f,"TowerSpr/Second"));
}
}
```

Это и быстрее и можно в момент инициализации проверять что второй объект с конструтором в сцене случайно создан не был. А в башнях обращаемся к нему вот так `GameLogic.instance.AllTowers [(int)selftype]`